# Automate Deployment for OOB web parts, pages , SP designer changes in SharePoint 2013

Tags: content-deployment

I would like to know what approach should be used in order to deploy the OOB web parts like CQWP,CE web part, web part pages designed in SP Designer, List , library etc.  instead of re-creating entire site and adding the web parts again in some other site collection or web application. I do not want to re create entire structure and pages , web parts etc.

I do not want to use wsp approach. 
Is there any way to automate the deployment process using some scripts.
What else can I do?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint uses features to add functionality like WebParts, Lists etc to site.

SharePoint has some Out Of The Box WebPart like the CQWP. To enable this WebPart you must for example enable the Publishing Features on the site collection for the web part to.

This feature can be can be activated from the **Site Settings** and Site collection features screen.
The feature can also be enabled by **[PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx)**.

```
Enable-SPFeature –identity "MyCustom" -URL http://somesite
```

With PowerShell its also possible to provision a Page with a CQWP on it.

For example to add a publishingpage you can use something like this

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb <url site here>
$pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$pWeb.AddPublishingPage()
...
```

Here you can find a tutorial on how to [add a webpart to a page](http://adicodes.com/adding-web-part-to-page-with-powershell/)

Comment: I do not want to create a publishing page and den adda web part. Basically i am looking for deployment of SharePoint site options just like Back up restore or Site template , etc. Do we have any other option to deploy. For ex: some changes are made in Sp designer to master pages , or i have modified have added CQWP etc, how can i deploy these features instead of re creating it on another site.

Comment: It was an example of what you can do to automate deployments without a WSP.

Comment: if you are looking for some site provision techiniques maybe this is helpfull http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could save site as template (source) and restore it on the destination. Back or restore is also an option.

The only drawback is the future upgrades/changes will require existing site to be replaced with the restored version.

Packaging without a WSP is really hard and prone to errors in different staging environments.